# Esent LogFileCorrupt-Exception

Tags: c#, esent

I'm using [ManagedEsent Library](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ManagedEsentDocumentation&referringTitle=Documentation) to read data from **Internet Explorer's** Cache using the **WebCacheV01.dat** file. I get the exception below everytime, despite changing the WebCacheV01.dat severally from different machines.

> Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentLogFileCorruptException: 'Log file
>   is corrupt'

Has anyone else encountered this before? How did you go about it? I have attached a screenshot to show where the exception is thrown.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things going on here:

- Creating the `Instance` is expensive. It should be done once, and reused. Every time you create an `Instance` it reads megabytes of log files to ensure that everything was cleaned up.
- `Session` isn't too expensive. If you have a server-scale application, then you should reuse sessions, but at small scale it doesn't matter much.
- You aren't setting the parameters to the `Instance`, such as the log file path, the log file prefix (I think its `v01` for webcache?)
- Check out the Windows Application event viewer, looking for category `ESENT` events. The exact log file location should be present in the event log entries.
- It is *not* supported to directly access these files. If you modify the files, then the web cache may malfunction.
- If it's for forensic purposes, then open up a case with MS and get the forensics folks involved. There is supposed to be a channel to help law-enforcement folks do their jobs.
- You mentioned different machines. If you copy the files from a different machine, then it may be in a different format that an older version of windows simply doesn't understand. `esent.dll` can read older files, but not files from the future.

Hope that helps,

-martin